# MySQL select specific data (Moodle)

Tags: mysql, moodle

This is just a simple question but for a beginner like me this is a little bit hard.

```
SELECT u.username AS 'User name',
CONCAT(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) AS 'Full Name',
u.department AS 'department',
c.fullname AS 'Course',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timeenrolled),'%m/%d/%Y') AS 'Enrollment Date',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),'%m/%d/%Y') AS 'Completion Date',
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'Expiration Date' 

FROM prefix_user AS u
JOIN prefix_course_completions AS p ON p.userid = u.id
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON p.course = c.id
```

in the `u.department AS 'department'` can I do something like

`SELECT u.department WHERE data="Science Department" AS 'department'`

I just want to select the users from a specific department in the report. How do I do that?

I am using the Configurable reports plugin for Moodle.

Comment: Just add `WHERE data = 'Science Department'` below the joins in your query.

Comment: So it will become like this:

`FROM prefix_user AS u
JOIN prefix_course_completions AS p ON p.userid = u.id
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON p.course = c.id

WHERE u.department = 'Science Department'`

am I right sir? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Looks correct to me.  Try it and let us know.

Comment: Look at the syntax of `SELECT` statements in the MySQL documentation. `SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ... WHERE ...`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just tested some users to complete their courses. It works like a charm. Thanks and Advance merry x-mas and happy new year!